# Can't svn commit using meld

Tags: svn, meld

I can't svn commit using meld, but command line svn works fine.
The error messages are below:

> QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
>
> svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
>
> svn: E215004: コミットに失敗しました (詳しい理由は以下のとおりです):
>   svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
>   'http://subversion/foo/bar'
>
> svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
>
> Authentication failed
>
> Exit code: 1

Could anyone solve this?

meld 1.8.4

ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this defect does not occur any more.
I think rebooting Linux remove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per the error you have to solve authentication problem:

```
svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
```

If you have to use Basic authentication, try passing the credentials as `--username MyUser` and `--password Pa$$w0rD`.

Comment: Thanks, bahrep. But I can commit from command line subversion.
I think "svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times." is root cause of this.
But I don't know where meld stores credentials data.